# VS function that must start with a letter, but accept numbers after the letter

Tags: c#

I need to create a VS function that must start with a letter, but accept numbers after the letter. I have this so far, but clearly not what I am looking for.

```
`If (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(txtLotNumber.Text = 
string.Concat(txtLotNumber.Text.Where(char.IsLetterOrDigit))))
{
     MessageBox.Show("Please enter letters and numbers at Supply Lot 
     field");
            return;
 }`
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. What is your question or problem? Make sure to take read [ask].

Comment: What is a VS function? Do you mean a c# function?

Comment: Are you saying you want to make a C# method (sometimes called a function) that takes a string, and checks if that string starts with a letter and the remaining characters are either letters or digits?

Comment: Sorry guys, I did not format correctly. Hopefully it will have better overview of the question now. tks

Comment: I need to create a method that only allows to accept letters at the first characters, but cannot start with numbers, only letters, then can accept numbers after that. Ex. HPT-0123. But would generate error if scan a barcode with numbers first. tks

Comment: You probably mean something like: `if (char.IsDigit(txtLotNumber.Text[0])) MessageBox.Show ("Too bad");`. Add a null check before that.

Comment: please give some real example.

Comment: Hello all, there's one field that I can accept only numbers, no letters, and it works all good. For example: 'if (System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.IsMatch(txtContainNum.Text, "[^0-9]" ))
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Please enter only numbers at Supply Container field.");
                return;
            }'

Comment: I was trying to work on something that blocks the numbers first, accept letters, then can accept number after I add the letters, like TRP-0223.. for example. Thank you all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I end up adding the first letters to my code, and enforcing with must add 3 letters to the beginning of the number scanned {3} and with that , it worked.

```
 if (!System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.IsMatch(txtLotNumber.Text, "^[A-Z]{3}[0-9-]"))

        {
            MessageBox.Show("Please scan Supplier Lot barcode at Supply Lot field");
            return;
        }
```

Answer (score -1):

regular expressions can help you, assuming you are using C# this code will evaluate your string and return true if it matches the pattern you describe.

```
 public bool testPattern(string sampleString)
 {
        string pattern = @"^[a-zA-Z][0-9]+$"; //Starts with letter and then any amount of numbers
        Match match = Regex.Match(sampleString, pattern, RegexOptions.None);
        return match.Success;
 }
```

You can read more about Regular Expressions searching this forum or in this link
https://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html

Comment: Thank you DouadyRabbit, but I just need to be able to have a method to block a number first, and to accept letters first then letters. My string works but it does accept either one.